# .setImage usage help Java

Tags: java, imageicon

I'm totally new to the language and I am trying to understand how ImageIcon works. I have a method within a sub-class and I want to return an ImageIcon based on a switch statement. The only problem I have is that I cannot seem to get .setImage() to work. I know that the syntax is setImage(Image image), but I'm not sure what (Image image) actually means within the parameters.

Here's the code I have below. I have tried searching but none seem to be specific to my issue. Thanks.

```
public ImageIcon getImage()
{
    ImageIcon bxIcon = new ImageIcon("g.jpg");

    switch(zone)
        {
            case 'a': bxIcon.setImage("sml.jpg");
                break;  
            case 'b': bxIcon.setImage("med.jpg");
                break;
            case 'c': bxIcon.setImage("lrg.jpg");
                break;
        }

    return boxIcon;
}
```

I know the above code wont compile as the syntax is incorrect, I'm just not sure how to use it properly. I have tried reading the Java info on .setImage() but cant find anything that would solve my issue. Any help would be great!

Comment: Why do you want to call setImage()? Just **create** an ImageIcon with the appropriate file name instead. setImage() takes an Image as argument. A String is not an Image.

Comment: The reason i picked this approach was because i need to return an ImageIcon. Not sure how i would be able to do this as i can only return one ImageIcon, which i chose as boxIcon.  I thought have return boxIcon and declaring what boxIcon is before the return would be the correct way.

Is there a way to return from a selection of ImageIcons?   for example having smIcon = new ImageIcon("a.jpg"),  mdIcon = new ImageIcon("b.jpg").........?

Answer (score 2):

In your code you can just return a new ImageIcon rather than relying on setting the image

```
public ImageIcom getImage(){
    switch(zone)
    {
        case 'a': return new ImageIcon("sml.jpg");
        //etc...
    }
    return new ImageIcon("g.jpg");
}
```

As an explanation about the setImage method: an [Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) is an interface, a common class which implements this interface is [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html). You can read an image file into a BufferedImage object using [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html). See [Reading/Loading an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) tutorial. As an example, you could read the Image and then set the Image of the Icon

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("sml.jpg"));
//Above could also be defined as an Image
bxIcon.setImage(image);
```

Comment: Thanks, dont know why i didnt think of having the return in the switch. That would do exactly what i am looking for!

But just for future reference, could you possibly tell me what the (Image image) parameter would refer to and how it would be used?

From looking at it, it looks as if you can just delcare a new image within the parameter?

Comment: I tried the above, but still wont compile for me as its not saying my method is missing a return statement.  Will i need to declare what is being return outside of the statement?

Comment: The method defines that it must return something. If there is no default statement in the switch, or final return of an ImageIcon there will be a compile time error.

Comment: @copeg Thats what i have just discovered, but how can i declare what to return if its dependant on the switch statement?  If i declare the return outside of the switch wont that override the switch statement?

Comment: Well, you need to return something so there should be a default value. Only if the switch falls through (no default value and zone does not match any case) will the final default value get returned

Comment: Oh thanks for clearing that up for me, so i could just return null; and it will only return this is the switch statement doesn't get fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

Well let's look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#setImage(java.awt.Image)).

The signature of the method is `public void setImage(Image image)`. This means that it accepts an `Image` object. You're passing it a `String`, so this approach won't work, but as the ever wise JB pointed out in the comments, one can simply create it!

`ImageIcon` has a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon(java.lang.String)) that allows the user to create an `ImageIcon` straight from the file.

```
 new ImageIcon("img1.jpg");
```

**Edit** : As JB has pointed out, `ImageIO` can be used to load the `Image` object, which is then passed to the `ImageIcon`.

Comment: But it's usually better to use `ImageIO` to get the Image as a resource.